# MySQL Sort by DESC results gap in records. No Missing record w/ sort ASC?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sorting

I'm going to refrain from posting my massive code block and just start exactly what I nailed the issued down to.

**I'm running this query:**

```
...
SELECT id, Title, images, recdate, 'item' AS type
  FROM ads_list
 WHERE to_days(now())<= (to_days(recdate)+14)
 ORDER BY recdate DESC
 LIMIT $offset, $listsperpage
...
```

This is for a pagination script. My *$offset* is just a count of the current records position and *$listsperpage* is set to an arbitrary number per pages (and this is set to 24). So there are supposed to be 24 results per page...

**Everything is working perfectly fine EXCEPT, when I run my query in DESC** by recdate sort, there are only 23 records outputted in my array on the first page??

**And if I run with ASC sort,** there are 24 records that display as expected on each page.

My recdate field is formatted like so:

```
2012-01-14 07:10:33
2012-01-14 07:10:35
2012-01-14 07:10:38
2012-01-14 07:10:30 ...
```

I also tried to do a DESC sort by id (auto) and still the first result array only contains 23 records, but the total array are all expected records.

I found the "missing" record from the first result is actually pushed forward, so its as if there is just a gap in the results with DESC. And that array is pushed completely forward to the last results page.. So all items are shifted one slot it appears.

I did not want to post up my entire code block because it's a lot, and I've spent a few hours testing and trying variations of my code, so I really think it's something to do with the SQL sort.

I just can't see my DESC would cause this oddity and ASC sort shows as normal.

Comment: Here is my php code structured and color coded: http://codetidy.com/1772/

Comment: Ahh I edited right as I was submitting it.. deleted that dup.

Comment: Why the `count++` is inside the `if ($list["images"] != "") { ... }` structure? Perhaps some images are blank?

Comment: Irrelevant to the issue: You could write the `WHERE to_days(now())<=(to_days(recdate)+14)` as: `WHERE recdate >= CURDATE()-INTERVAL 14 DAY` so it doesn't have to scan the whole table but use an index on `recdate` (if there is one)

Comment: The count++ is for the actual output counts for the display formatting. It's not related to the.. I checked and all images are linked properly. The record is not missing, it just won't display on the first page when using DESC sort.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured this nightmare out!

I still can't explain why it happens, but at least I am getting full expected results now.

In my while loop, I check the $list["images"] != "". I turns out when using DESC sort on recdate, there is a blank array value, so it evaluates to true and "drops" that listing from the page. So I added $list["images"] == "" and now the image and data displays for that array item.